# Search for string in PHP Array

Tags: php

When I run `var_dump($leader_member);` I get this array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "leader"
}
```

How do I then search this array for the word `leader`?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: Try to read manuals first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code might look like this due to the lack of provided information:

```
$leader_member = array( "leader" );
var_dump($leader_member);
```

A possible solution would be something similar to this:

```
if( in_array( "leader", $leader_member ) ) {
    echo "leader found in array";
} else {
    echo "leader not found in array";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Built-in in_array() or array_search():

```
in_array('leader', $array) //return bool

array_search('leader',  $array) //return int key if elements exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$key = array_search('leader', $leader_member);
```